# Spring Boot integration test of login with authentication, exception doesn't throw

Tags: java, spring, testing, mockmvc

My problem is that I'm trying to do integration test with /login endpoint. Everything is fine but when I test that it throws and BadCredentialsException when password doesn't match the user, then exception is thrown but assertion fails. Code below

```
    @DisplayName("Should throw BadCredentialsException when password doesn't match, HTTP status 401")
    @Test
    void shouldThrowBadCredentialsException_WhenPasswordDoesntMatch() throws Exception {
        LoginDTO login = new LoginDTO(USER_JWT, INVALID);
        String json = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(login);

        mockMvc.perform(post(LOGIN_ENDPOINT)
                        .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                        .content(json))
                .andExpect(status().is(401))
                .andExpect(result -> Assertions.assertTrue(result.getResolvedException() instanceof BadCredentialsException));
```

Message in console

```
org.springframework.security.authentication.BadCredentialsException: Password is wrong.
    at huberts.spring.forumapp.security.AuthManager.authenticate(AuthManager.java:40) ~[classes/:na]
    at huberts.spring.forumapp.security.filter.AuthFilter.attemptAuthentication(AuthFilter.java:39) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:231) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.0.jar:6.0.0]



org.opentest4j.AssertionFailedError: 
Expected :true
Actual   :false
<Click to see difference>
```

AuthenticationManager class

```
@Override
    public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {
        String username = authentication.getPrincipal().toString();
        String password = authentication.getCredentials().toString();

        if (username.isBlank() || password.isBlank()) {
            log.error("An exception occurred!", new BadCredentialsException(LOGIN_OR_PASSWORD_IS_WRONG));
            throw new BadCredentialsException(LOGIN_OR_PASSWORD_IS_WRONG);
        }

        UserDetails user = service.loadUserByUsername(username);

        if (!passwordEncoder.matches(password, user.getPassword())){
            log.error("An exception occurred!", new BadCredentialsException(PASSWORD_IS_WRONG));
            throw new BadCredentialsException(PASSWORD_IS_WRONG);
        }
        if (!user.isAccountNonLocked()) {
            log.error("An exception occurred!", new AccountBlockedException(ACCOUNT_BLOCKED_EXCEPTION));
            throw new AccountBlockedException(ACCOUNT_BLOCKED_EXCEPTION);
        }

        return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(user.getUsername(), user.getPassword(), user.getAuthorities());
    }
```

Login endpoint

```
    @PostMapping("/login")
    ResponseEntity<Void> loginUser (@RequestBody LoginDTO credentials) {
        return ResponseEntity.ok().build();
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure that passwords from `password` and `user.getPassword()` don't match? Did you try recompiling your application before running it?

Comment: @geobreze since in console I'm getting error exception message from log that it's actually throwing exception, yes I'm sure. Maybe it's something with those AuthenticationException, maybe it's catching throw, honestly I don't know.

Comment: So, as I can see from your test case, you're expecting `BadCredentialsException`, but getting `AccountBlockedException`. This means that line `!passwordEncoder.matches(password, user.getPassword())` evaluates to `false`. So my assumption is either your `passwordEncoder` always returns true or passwords indeed match.

Comment: @geobreze  Throw of AccountBlockedException was a mistake of writing question so it's my bad. As I tried to test login with wrong password I get BadCredentialsException, but no success of assertions. 

`Expected :true
Actual   :false`

Comment: Adding some additional logging when testing `@Controller`s helped a lot for me. Did you try to add ```logging.level.web=DEBUG
spring.mvc.log-request-details=true
spring.mvc.log-resolved-exception=true``` in your application.properties?

Comment: @StefanBillmaier Still none of this works. For now i removed expecting the instance of exception class thrown and only asserting the status of method result but thank you for trying to help.

Comment: @huga721 you can try running this test with debugger attached and trying to evaluate a result of `passwordEncoder.matches(password, user.getPassword()`. Maybe you have mocked `passwordEncoder` in other test